# Do E. coli produce both cellulose and curli?

Tags: bacteriology

I read a paper that describes a specific stain for cellulose and curli (simultaneously) in Salmonella. I think this should work for E. coli but I'm not sure if all strains produce it. If they do, are the tertiary structures similar to those from salmonella?

[Real-time optotracing of curli and cellulose in live Salmonella biofilms using luminescent oligothiophenes](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/npjbiofilms.2016.24)